# Open Form where number LIKE input value

Tags: ms-access, vba

Basically, I need to be able to pull up a list of all parts in a certain category type based on a textbox input. I currently have a form list of all `Catalog` numbers named "_NextPartSearch". For example, take Catalog number `EDF50-00159`, where EDF50 is the category type and 00159 is the number itself.

With my textbox (called "NextPartValue"), I want to be able to type in EDF50 and have ALL of the part numbers show up (EDF50-00000 through EDF50-99999).

My code thus far is as follows:

```
Private Sub NextPartValue_AfterUpdate()

Dim strWhereCondition As String

    strWhereCondition = "[CATALOG] = '" & Me!NextPartValue & "'"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "_NextPartSearch", acFormDS, , strWhereCondition

End Sub
```

The code above brings up the correct part ONLY if the whole catalog number is typed in, otherwise it returns nothing. I've tried using `Like` statements, such as `strWhereCondition = "[CATALOG] = '" LIKE Me!NextPartValue & "*"`, but none of them have worked. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `Like` keyword into your `strWhereCondition` string --- so that it is basically the same as a `WHERE` clause in a query but without the word `WHERE`.  And don't use both `=` and `Like` for the same criterion.  Also include `Debug.Print` so you can inspect the string built by the code.

```vb
strWhereCondition = "[CATALOG] Like '" & Me!NextPartValue & "*'"
Debug.Print strWhereCondition '<- inspect in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
```